# Python code working in one editor and not on the other

Tags: python, string, numbers, syntax-error, addition

I am new in learning Python. In this code, I am trying to add 2 numerical Strings. In my editor, PyCharm, in line 13, I wrote the statement below. It didn't worked. I tried to write
sumation: int = int(x) +int(y) + int(left_over)

and it worked. However, on leetcode, it is not working. It says that there is an invalid syntax in line 14. In leetcode I was writing in Python as well, not Python3.

```
class Solution(object):
    def addStrings(num1, num2):
        last = ""
        left_over = 0
        i = len(num1) - 1
        j = len(num2) - 1
        while (i >= 0) or (j >= 0):
            x = 0
            y = 0
            if i >= 0:
                x = num1[i]
            if j >= 0:
                y = num2[j]
            **sumation = x + y + left_over
            left_over = sumation // 10
            last = str(sumation % 10) + last
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        if left_over > 0:
            last = str(left_over) + last
        return last
```

Comment: "It says that there is an invalid syntax" - please provide the full error message

Comment: `**sumation = ...` isn’t valid syntax.

Comment: remove the `**` from `**sumation = ...`?

Answer (score 0):

There was a small bug in this line

```
**sumation = x + y + left_over
```

which I guess you'd wanted to do something like:

```
summation = int(x) + int(y) + left_over
```

Also you've probably forgotten to pass `self` in `addStrings()`.

```
def addStrings(self, num1, num2):
```

Just tested your solution, passed on LeetCode:

```
class Solution(object):
    def addStrings(self, num1, num2):
        last = ""
        left_over = 0
        i = len(num1) - 1
        j = len(num2) - 1
        while (i >= 0) or (j >= 0):
            x = 0
            y = 0
            if i >= 0:
                x = num1[i]
            if j >= 0:
                y = num2[j]

            summation = int(x) + int(y) + left_over
            left_over = summation // 10
            last = str(summation % 10) + last
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        if left_over > 0:
            last = str(left_over) + last
        return last


print(Solution().addStrings("100", "500"))
```

Prints,

```
600
```

---

This'll also work OK:

```
class Solution:
    def addStrings(self, num1, num2):
        length1, length2 = len(num1), len(num2)
        reversed_num1, reversed_num2 = num1[::-1], num2[::-1]
        max_length = max(length1, length2)
        added_num = ''
        carry = index = 0
        while index < max_length or carry:
            digit1 = int(reversed_num1[index]) if index < length1 else 0
            digit2 = int(reversed_num2[index]) if index < length2 else 0
            added_digit = (digit1 + digit2 + carry) % 10
            carry = (digit1 + digit2 + carry) // 10
            added_num += str(added_digit)
            index += 1

        return added_num[::-1]
```

Here is also a Python template that I use:

```
from typing import List
import collections
import itertools
import functools
import math
import string
import random
import bisect
import re
import operator
import heapq
import queue

from queue import PriorityQueue
from itertools import combinations, permutations
from functools import lru_cache
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import deque
from collections import Counter


class Solution(object):
    def addStrings(self, num1, num2):
        last = ""
        left_over = 0
        i = len(num1) - 1
        j = len(num2) - 1
        while (i >= 0) or (j >= 0):
            x = 0
            y = 0
            if i >= 0:
                x = num1[i]
            if j >= 0:
                y = num2[j]

            summation = int(x) + int(y) + left_over
            left_over = summation // 10
            last = str(summation % 10) + last
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        if left_over > 0:
            last = str(left_over) + last
        return last


print(Solution().addStrings("100", "500"))  # 600
# print(Solution().()) #
# print(Solution().()) #
# print(Solution().()) #
# print(Solution().()) #
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-strings/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Thank you. But I have a small question, Why do we need to cast x and y if I already initiate them to 0, doesn't Python recognize that they are integers?